# Installing Visual studio 2010: ERROR - VC 10.0 Runtime (x86)

Tags: c#, installation

*Hi, I get the following error while trying to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, on my Windows Xp machine:* The following components failed to install VC 10.0 Runtime (x86)

Here is the error log:

```
[05/17/12,11:26:36] VC 9.0 Runtime (x86): [2] dlmgr: CDownloadJobCompositeImpl: Download completed with hr = 0x800b0101
[05/17/12,11:26:37] VC 9.0 Runtime (x86): [2] Failed to fetch setup file in CBaseComponent::PreInstall()
[05/17/12,11:26:37] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147467260.
[05/17/12,11:26:37] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::RunInstallPhase() - Call to Pre/Install/Post for InstallComponents failed
[05/17/12,11:26:37] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::RunInstallPhaseAndCheckResults() - RunInstallPhase() returned a NULL piActionResults
[05/17/12,11:26:37] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::RunInstallFromList() - RunInstallPhaseAndCheckResults failed [2]
[05/17/12,11:26:37] setup.exe: [2] ISetupManager::RunInstallLists(IP_PREINSTALL failed in ISetupManager::RunInstallFromThread()
[05/17/12,11:26:37] setup.exe: [2] ISetupManager::RunInstallFromThread() failed in ISetupManager::RunInstall()
```

** any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Have you had VS on this machine before ?

Comment: That error code is CERT_E_EXPIRED, "A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp".  You'd better check the clock on your machine first.  Avoid trying to work around expired demo versions of VS2010.

Comment: @HansPassant : where is this certificate? and how can i check when it expires? Thank You.

Comment: This needs to work the other way around.  You'll need to explain why the log file says it is May 17th when you ask this question on July 20th.  Why have you changed the clock on your machine?

Answer (score 2):

Error code `0x800b0101`, from the first line, seems to indicate a certificate issue, like @Hans said. It's likely that some Windows Updates fail to be installed and report the same error (although you might not see them yet as you don't have VS installed yet).

Check [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/88da4438-9c59-411c-99c4-1df7866f24ff).

I stumbled upon this error code when trying to install certain security updates for Visual Studio (from Windows Update). I solved it running a specific FixIt .msi file. If the suggestions in the thread don't work, please tell me and I'll check which exact FixIt I ran.

Comment: that didn't help . please tell me the fixit

Comment: It might be FixIt 50528, or 50652. I cleaned up my browser history so I can't tell for sure. What I do recall is having gone to the [Microsoft Fix it Solution Center](http://support.microsoft.com/fixit/en-us), selecting Windows as problem area, Install or upgrade software or hardware in "What are you trying to do?" and "Windows Update" as sub section. Then I browsed through the 27 available FixIts until I found the most suitable. From looking at them again, it's likely one of the two I said at first. It was a pain to find that FixIt.

Comment: By the way, not having the correct date might be an issue, like @Hans commented. You could sync the clock before the install, finish it and then go back to your previous date setting.

Comment: what should i change the date to?

Comment: Double click the date in the taskbar, go to the Internet Time tab and check "Automatically synchronize with an Internet Time server"

Comment: I can't find the Internet Time tab?

Comment: Configuration issue. Read [this thread](http://board.homeseer.com/showthread.php?t=81910).